# React visual regression testing options

Tags: reactjs, testing

What do you use to test visual regression in React? I would like to have some setup which would work in the similar manner as snapshots testing where you could pass component, create reference image and make further comparison based on that reference.

Comment: https://github.com/fwouts/react-screenshot-test

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks